# Postgres Alternative to \du to view group role membership

Tags: postgresql, psql, roles

Is there an alternative to using `psql \du` to retrieve the `Member of` column using a builtin Postgres function or view? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In **psql** you can echo the actual queries generated by backslash commands.

Use the `--echo-hidden` parameter

```
psql --echo-hidden ...
```

or set the variable `ECHO_HIDDEN` in psql, example:

```
test=# \set ECHO_HIDDEN on
test=# \du
********* QUERY **********
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
ORDER BY 1;
******************************
```

Read about psql [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out and here's my answer:

```
SELECT
  pg_roles.rolname,
  pg_auth_members.member,
  (SELECT pg_roles.rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE oid = pg_auth_members.member)
FROM
  pg_roles, pg_auth_members
WHERE
  pg_auth_members.roleid = ( SELECT oid FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'my_group') and pg_roles.rolname = 'my_group';
```

So, this query would return something like this:

```
   rolname  | member | rolname 
------------+--------+---------
   my_group |  18068 | first_member
   my_group |  18069 | second_member
(2 rows)
```